Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets with another table INDIRECT
I want to highlight names in A7:A in color on the target sheet if a checkbox is marked in the source table "Data" (TRUE):
Source table "Data":
Column A:A = Checkbox
Column B:B = Names
The formula must first check the names of the target sheet with the names of the sheet Data!B:B and then check whether the checkbox in Data!A:A is set to TRUE.
I use semicolons as a separator, but I can't get any further. I think INDIRECT must be used?
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A7)); COUNTIF(Data!B:B; A7) > 0; VLOOKUP(A7; Data!B:A; 2; FALSE))


Try this alternative solution
=AND(INDIRECT("Data!B:B")=A7, INDIRECT("Data!A:A")=TRUE)

This formula uses INDIRECT to reference the Data sheet columns and checks if the name in the target sheet matches the name in "Data!B:B" and whether the checkbox in "Data!A:A" is TRUE. The AND function ensures that both conditions must be true for the formatting to be applied. If either condition is false, the formatting will not be applied.
References

AND
INDIRECT


This works for me, thank you. I find out, this also works for my situation:
=AND(COUNTIF( indirect("Data!B:B"); A7) > 0; FILTER( indirect("Data!A:A"); indirect("Data!B:B") = A7))


You may try:
=xmatch(TRUE&A7;index(indirect("Data!A:A")&indirect("Data!B:B")))

